# android-NullPointerException on settext for a textView

Tags: android, textview, android-debug

I've published an application , it's been downloaded about 5000 times . I've tested it on 4 different devices and lot more people said that it works fine , although , there are some users that app caches for them . this is the code :

```
TextView tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(DariGlyphUtils.reshapeText(MainActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.type)));
```

It's call when someone click on an imageButton on ActionBar and it opens a dialog and set a text for textviews in it . there are about 20 other textViews on this dialog that I set the text for them either.

I need to set text pragmatically , because the language is farsi and I should use DariGlyphUtils class to make the text right for older devices .

What do you think is the problem that It crashes on some devices ?

this is the whole error :

```
STACK_TRACE = java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ir.klach.persiandesigners.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:966)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4503)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

PHONE_MODEL = IdeaTab A2107A-H
ANDROID_VERSION = 4.0.3
```

Line MainActivity.java:966 is the second line ("tv.setText....")

could you help me

thank you

Comment: Firstly, change `MainActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.type)` to `getResources().getString(R.string.type)`. And is `reshapeText` a static method? Did you debug what's null?

Comment: try to put code at line 966.

Comment: Either `tv` is null either `getResources()` returns `null`. Certainly your dialog hasn't the required view (yet)

Comment: The TextView can be null, activity can be null, or DariGlyphUtils can be null. You need to debug and check what is null. And you should also add checks to ensure nothing is null before applying your tv.setText.

Comment: Could you post source for `DariGlyphUtils.reshapeText`. It may be that this method returns null for some imputs.

Comment: @BartoszBilicki if that was the case it would be in the stacktrace

Comment: @DavidOlsson  thanks for the reply , How can I debug it when it is not creches on my devices and emulators ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#findViewById(int)

Comment: @MysticMagic thanks for the reply , How can I debug it when it is not creches on my devices and emulators ?

Comment: Make more tests for it. Possibly make a debug application that you send to the users that have been able to crash it. Ask them what they did. A first guess is that they closed/put the app into background before it tried to apply tv.setText (so that MainActivity.this is null).

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that the dialog is not showing and so the TextView can not be found.
Maybe a simple check if the dialog is showing could help before you start populating your views.
Or you simply do this within your (custom) dialog and get rid of the root cause.

BTW: MainActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.type) -> getString(R.string.type)

Answer (score 0):

Check this line :

```
TextView tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv);
```

Weather Textview id "tv" exist in the layout file of your declared in

```
setContentView(R.layout.<YOUR LAYOUT FILE>);
```

Since all ids of all the layout files inside the layout folder are declared inside the **R.java** file. So, you might be creating a reference for an id which is not in your declare layout file.